# mysql++ global table variable

Tags: c++, mysqlpp

I have read through the documentation, and looked at the examples, but I still can't figure out how to assign a table to a global variable in C++.  I might be a little spoiled. I'm coming from python and assigning a table to a global variable is really a simple matter using mysqldb.

Can a table be assigned to a global variable to be accessed outside the mysqlpp class?

As an example, when the following code is compiled, I get the error: error: ‘sched_recs’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <mysql++.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlpp;

int SSE (const char* timeStr)
{
  time_t sse;
  struct tm tm;
  strptime(timeStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
  sse = mktime(&tm);
  return (sse);
}

int main()
{
  string table = "sched_recs";
  time_t now, tt; 
  now = time(NULL);

  try
  {
  // Connect to the sample database.
  mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
  //             databasename,    host,   username, password
  if (conn.connect("dbname", "dbhost", "dbusername", "dbpasswd")) {
      // Retrieve a subset of the sample stock table set up by resetdb
      // and display it.
      //stmt = "select datetime from %s", table 
      mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("select * from sched_recs");
      mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult sched_recs = query.store();
      //if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult tableData = query.store()) {
          ////cout << "We have:" << endl;

      //}
  }
  }
  catch (Exception& e)
  {
    cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sched_recs.num_rows(); ++i) {
    if (SSE(sched_recs[i][1]) - 60 * 3 < now && SSE(sched_recs[i][2]) > now)
    {
      cout << '\t' << sched_recs[i][1] << endl;
      //system("at -f test.py '18:30' today");
    }
  }

}
```

If I instead move the for loop back into the class, then everything works fine, but this is limiting.  Is this the only way to do it?  All the examples seem to make it seem so.

Comment: What documentation (a link would be nice).

Comment: It sounds like this is done via SSQLS, but looking at chapter 5 of the [documentation](http://www.tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/ssqls.html). Do I really have to define a data member for each SQL column in the table or just the ones that I want to request?  The docs make it sound like I have to define one for every column in the table: "which has a data member for each SQL column, using the same names".

Comment: Please note that you have declared `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult sched_recs` inside the `try{}` block and therefore when the block ends, the variable gets out of scope and it cannot be used outside the of the try block.  Move the `for` loop inside the `try{}` block or move the variable declaration before the `try{}` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yaniro suggested.

Try the following snippet of code

```
#include <mysql++.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlpp;

int SSE (const char* timeStr)
{
  time_t sse;
  struct tm tm;
  strptime(timeStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
  sse = mktime(&tm);
  return (sse);
}

int main()
{
  string table = "sched_recs";
  mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult sched_recs;
  time_t now, tt; 
  now = time(NULL);

  try
  {
  // Connect to the sample database.
  mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
  //             databasename,    host,   username, password
  if (conn.connect("dbname", "dbhost", "dbusername", "dbpasswd")) {
      // Retrieve a subset of the sample stock table set up by resetdb
      // and display it.
      //stmt = "select datetime from %s", table 
      mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("select * from sched_recs");
      sched_recs = query.store();
      //if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult tableData = query.store()) {
          ////cout << "We have:" << endl;

      //}
  }
  }
  catch (Exception& e)
  {
    cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sched_recs.num_rows(); ++i) {
    if (SSE(sched_recs[i][1]) - 60 * 3 < now && SSE(sched_recs[i][2]) > now)
    {
      cout << '\t' << sched_recs[i][1] << endl;
      //system("at -f test.py '18:30' today");
    }
  }

}
```

Note that only difference in this sample and the one you posted is the location of the declaration of the `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult` variable called `sched_recs`.

In this sample it is declared in the scope of main , rather than the scope of the try block, so the variable's value is still in scope after the try block finishes.

For more information about try and catch block scope see [Exception dangers and downsides](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/156-exception-dangers-and-downsides/).

Comment: Thank you @yaniro and Appleman1234 for your help.  That works great.   What a relief, that SSQLS stuff looked like a lot more than what I needed. That try/catch behavior, with respect to variable scope, is much different than try/except in python.  Thanks again.